# How do I solve this algorithm in finding the distance between origin and remotepoint?

Tags: java, oop

**Main Class**

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Q6_7_Muhammed_Irshath {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TwoDPoint twodpoint = new TwoDPoint(); // Created an object for TwoDPoint class
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Created this to test input

        for (int i = 0; i < 1;i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter value for x: ");
            double x = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter value for y: ");
            double y = sc.nextDouble();                 
        }            
    }
}
```

**TwoDPoint Class**

```java
import java.util.*;

public class TwoDPoint {

    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    TwoDPoint(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;  
    }

    TwoDPoint(double x, double y){

    }

    public static int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public static int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double findDistance(TwoDPoint remotepoint) {
        double distance = 0;

        TwoDPoint.getX();
        TwoDPoint.getY();

        distance =  
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

I have an algorithm where I have to find the distance between `origin(0,0)` and `remotepoint(x,y)` which has to be read input. My issue is how can I use `twodpoint object` to retrieve the (x,y) and put it in the `findDistance` method in `TwoDPoint Class`? And how to calculate the distance?

Please don't judge me I'm new to this. I can't even solve a simple question. This is the way I must use to solve the algorithm

Comment: Google: [distance between 2 points on a line](https://www.google.com/search?q=distance+between+2+points+on+a+line)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I saw that but all I want is just to improve the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try this and adapt the inputs as wanted (from console, etc)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SolveTwoP {
double x,y;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SolveTwoP sol = new SolveTwoP();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Created this to test input

    //no need loop here
    System.out.println("Please enter value for x: ");
    sol.x = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter value for y: ");
    sol.y = sc.nextDouble();                 

    double result = sol. new TwoDPoint().findDistance(sol.new TwoDPoint(sol.x,sol.y));
    System.out.println(result);

    //get an instance of solver and invoke with the point on x=3, y=4
    //solver TwoDPoint is also assign the coordinates

    //double result = sol. new TwoDPoint().findDistance(sol.new TwoDPoint(3,4));
    //System.out.println(result);

}
//inner class
class TwoDPoint {

    private  double x;
    private  double y;

    TwoDPoint()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;  
    }
    TwoDPoint(double x, double y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public Double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double findDistance(TwoDPoint remotepoint)
    {
        double distance = remotepoint.getX()*remotepoint.getX() + remotepoint.getY()*remotepoint.getY();
        distance = Math.sqrt(distance);
        return distance;   
    }
}
}
```

Output:`5.0` for `x=3` and `y=4` or reversed ...

 The formula is based on `Pitagora theorem` with `(0,0)` given as origin

Comment: check it now, but how to connect to various inputs should be basically a trivial task ...